# Scraping with Osmosis returns undefined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, osmosis

I'm using the `Osmosis` package to scrape like this:

```
require('osmosis')
   .get('https://samdb.org/phones/galaxy-s10')
   .find("//h4[contains(text(), 'MP')]")
   .data(data=>{
       console.log(data)
   })
```

My problem is that it logs an empty object to the console, but if I try this `xpath` on the website with `XPath helper` it returns that `h4` which I want. What am I missing?

Comment: you can be more specific in your selector ".f-content .two h4".

Comment: The selector is specific enough, in the log it says that one element was found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the .set after the .find method in your chain.

```
require('osmosis')
   .get('https://samdb.org/phones/galaxy-s10')
   .find("//h4[contains(text(), 'MP')]")
   .set('megapixel')
   .data(data=>{
       console.log(data)
   })
```